# why am I not able to create with this parameter in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise

I have a method with the following line:

```
26         User.create!(:email => "token@email.com", :linkedin_uid => linkedin_uid, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
```

Here is my controller:

```
20   def create
 21     @user = User.new(params[:user])
 22     if @user.save
 23       flash[:notice] = "Successfully created user."
 24       redirect_to @user
 25     else
 26       render :action => 'new'
 27     end
 28   end
```

Even from the rails console when I try to create it by passing the params :linkedin_uid, it still comes out nil.  :(

Here is the context for the line:

```
18   def self.find_for_linked_in_oauth(omniauth_hash, signed_in_resource=nil)
 19     debugger
 20     #omniauth_hash is a hash passed in from env["omniauth_hash"] by callback controller
 21     linkedin_uid = omniauth_hash['uid']
 22       debugger
 23       if user = User.find_by_linkedin_uid(linkedin_uid)
 24         user
 25       else # Create an user with a stub password. 
 26         User.create!(:email => "token@email.com", :linkedin_uid => linkedin_uid, :password => Devise.friendly_token[0,20]) 
 27       end
 28   end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that this is a User model from Devise. The problem here is likely that you haven't made `linkedin_uid` [mass-assignable](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment). You will need to do that in your `User` model via

```
attr_accessible :linkedin_uid
```

Whenever you defined fields with attr_accessible those become the ONLY fields that will be updated via [mass assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) functions.

Comment: hmmm, why does :email and :password get passed, but not linkedin_uid?

Comment: I thought you meant that the object wasn't being created. Now it seems pretty clear it's an `attr_accessible` problem. I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your data type for the linkedin_uid column in the database to make sure it can support the data you are giving it in the create method.